# NullPointerException when using mapping JSON to object with Jackson/Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have Glassfish server with Jersey used for webservices.
I'm sending a POST request with JSON in the body and want Jackson to map it to a JPA entity. 
That's when NPE comes up.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "tracks", schema = "public", catalog = "xtracker")
public class Track {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "track_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Long trackId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "time_start", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Timestamp timeStart;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "time_end", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Timestamp timeEnd;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "track")
    private List<Jump> jumps = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "track", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;
...getters and setters
```

REST method:

```
@POST
@Path("tracks")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Secured
public void addTrack(Track track) {
    System.out.println("track" + track.getTrackId());
}
```

The exception points to `track.getTrackId()`

**Jackson works normally**, because it's alright when I try to map simple Test object with only one field (without ManyToOne relations)

ApplicationConfig:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // following code can be used to customize Jersey 2.0 JSON provider:
        try {
            Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
            // Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature");
            // Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jettison.JettisonFeature");
            resources.add(jsonProvider);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        resources.add(SecurityFilter.class);
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically re-generated by NetBeans REST support to populate
     * given list with all resources defined in the project.
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(RestResource.class);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
This is an example of JSON that comes from client (I checked that it really reaches Jersey):

`{"jumps":[],"points":[{"pointId":0,"speed":0.2}]}`

(pointId and speed is Point fields)

**UPDATE 2:**
The problem resolved: it was RequestFilter clearing an http entity body and the null one was arriving to the method. Thanks!

Comment: Is `track` null in your example or is `trackId` null?

Comment: are there any errors or warning printed out before your NPE (warnings generated by Jackson) that might bring more clarity?

Comment: OMG thank you for update #2! I've been pulling my hair out over this one :(